# Runing java in terminal on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal, compilation

So my problem is how to run java class or anything from my terminal. I have HelloWorld.class and Helloworld.java files. How do I run them over terminal on Ubuntu?

Comment: java doesn't come installed by default on ubuntu, have you successfully installed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `java` file if you already have the `class`. Just run

```
java HelloWorld
```

Or is it `Helloworld`? Case is important!

Without the class, you can create it from the `java` file:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 on Ubuntu is.... difficult.

There are ways to get the JVM on an ubuntu-based system, but, ubuntu generally doesn't have support for Java. I recommend looking up the IcedTea package in the ubuntu package store or following the instructions here:

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux

If you've installed it already, using standard commands such as 'java' and 'javac' should work. Use javac to convert the .java into a .class file, and use java to run the class file.

```
javac HelloWorld.java && java HelloWorld.class
```